# How to position where a ckeditor plugin pops up?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a `ckeditor` instance, then under the editor is a listing of all posts in a thread. The `ckeditor` is used to edit a post.

When I click a plugin, say `smilies`, the `smilie` selector dialog appears half way down the lists of all posts in the thread. When a thread is long, that means scrolling down several screens worth of lines to find the `smilie` selector dialog.

This not only happens with `smilies`, but with any popup I select in the editor. I want all of the popups to appear at the top of the screen where the editor is, not somewhere in the middle.

Can someone help explain to me how to do this?

I believe I'm using version 4.something, but I'm not sure, and am not sure how to check it. I'm not new to programming, but I'm VERY new to `ckeditor`.